# active javascript that was inserted with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am trying to make Ajax pages more useful some are containing java script in them can that java script be activated somehow because so far i didn't find anything that might help me with it:

```
 <script>
   var d=document.getElementById("foo");
   d.innerHTML="<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yey');</script>";
 </script>
```

i want this to alert me the 'yey' but it naturaly doesnt any idias?
no j query please.

Comment: Totally poor design, don't do that at all.

Comment: what that has to do with design? I want to make it possible to edit the small pages without the need to enter the whole script...

Comment: why you want to do that. You are trying insert javascript using javascript. Why don't you simply use `alert('yey');` instead of `d.innerHTML="...."`

Comment: again if i want to alert(yey) i will need to edit the big script and i don't want that.I want to make it possible to import/export pages with Ajax that are very varied and different...

Comment: i however could run a function on d that will get all the script children and run then under window.setTimeout

Comment: I think you looking for `eval()`. Don't use eval! It is a dangerous function.

Comment: i dont look for eval() i posted scrypt below that works just fine

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying won't work because javascript is interpreted on the machine when the page is loaded, thus, when you are inserting your code, the whole script of the page has been already parsed by browser's javascript engine and the code you're inserting on the page is considered plain text by the engine.

The code won't be again sent to the engine until the page refreshes, but when it does so, the javascript you've inserted will dissapear, as it isn't there on page load.

What you need to do is to use some type of template/include system on your content.

Answer (score 0):

i got it!

```
var d=document.getElementById("foo");
 d.innerHTML="<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yey');</script>";

startScrypt(d);

function startScrypt(obj) {.
 if (!obj) return;
 var children=obj.childNodes;  
 for (var i in children) 
   if (children[i]){
                       if (children[i].tagName=="SCRIPT") { 
                          if (!children[i].src || children[i].src=="") 
                               window.setTimeout(children[i].innerHTML,0); 
                               else {load_scrit_src(children[i].src);}
                        }   else startScrypt(children[i]);
                   }
}
```

well that was nice...thank you all.

Comment: Hope to never browse a such designed site.

Comment: it's not website...it's part of cms... i would never make such a website...why i need it? to load pages from previous cms without having to rewrite them via Ajax, does that makes sence?